# How can I find resources for different language word lists?

Tags: dictionary, localization, puzzle

Hi I am looking for different language word lists similar to this one [here](http://svn.pietdepsi.com/repos/projects/zyzzyva/trunk/data/words/French/ODS5.txt), so that I can localize a word puzzle game I have created I can't seem to find any good links, I have found a Polish .txt file but that was because I asked my Polish friend to search in his language.  Any help would be great thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Even when searching with polish queries I wasn't too successful either. If you are on Ubuntu, you might want to consider installing packages like [wpolish](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/quantal/main/base/wpolish), [witalian](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/witalian), [wspanish](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hardy/+package/wspanish), or what else is available (further languages are probably easy to find, I think I see a pattern here...).

Those will store giant word list files in `/usr/share/dict/` which you could at least look up words in to determine if they exist.